# What's the difference between ComboBox_AddItemData() and ComboBox_AddString()?

Tags: winapi, combobox, itemscontrol

What's the difference between [`ComboBox_AddItemData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windowsx/nf-windowsx-combobox_additemdata) and [`ComboBox_AddString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windowsx/nf-windowsx-combobox_addstring)? from the documentation it is not clear to me. Does [`ComboBox_AddItemData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windowsx/nf-windowsx-combobox_additemdata) add a data to the combobox, in the sense of [`SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, dataInstance)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptrw)? and in that case, dataInstance can be somehow converted to string to be displayed in the combobox or it's a alias for [`ComboBox_AddString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windowsx/nf-windowsx-combobox_addstring), maybe there due to historical reasons?

Comment: no any difference at binary level. this adds new item to the list box of a combo box. only question of style. `ComboBox_AddString` have sense use when `CBS_HASSTRINGS` style is on, otherwise - use `ComboBox_AddItemData`. and of course `GWLP_USERDATA` here unrelated

Comment: The convenience macros (like `ComboBox_AddItemData`) expand to `SendMessage` calls. The documentation for the actual messages (like [CB_ADDSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-addstring)) usually has more complete documentation. `ComboBox_AddItemData` is similar to `GWLP_USERDATA` in that it allows client code to associate *arbitrary* data with an item. An owner-drawn combo box can then convert the item data into its string representation for display.